# SendAsync, called in IOCP callback overtakes an earlier SendAsync call that lead to the callback

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asynchronous, iocp

In a scenario where a socket mostly sends data and that looks basically like the following code snippet, I sometimes get reentrancy in `CompletedHandler`, where both calls made by IOCP framework, and the second callback, which is the result of `SendAsync` in the previous callback, overtaking the initiator. This is somewhat unexpected and leads to .Net resending the previous packet, instead of the new one as set by SetBuffer.

```
socketAsyncEventArgs.Completed = CompletedHandler;
...
void CompletedHandler(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    log(threadId + " A");
    socketAsyncEventArgs.SetBuffer(...);
    log(threadId + " B");
    _socket.SendAsync(socketAsyncEventArgs);
    log(threadId + " Z");
}
```

The log then reads:

```
1 A
1 B
2 A
2 B
1 Z
2 Z
```

Is this behavior to be expected? Or am I using it wrongly?

This basically means I'll have to either put the call to `SendAsync` into a critical section or use multiple SocketAsyncEventArgs, which I'm trying to avoid (otherwise I have to create a new one every time, or pool them, which also needs synchronization).

Comment: If `SendAsync` is the last "real" thing you do in your handler (other then the artificial logging), what is the problem this is causing you? (It *is* expected behavior, just to be clear)

Comment: @Amit See question: `This [...] leads to .Net resending the previous packet, instead of the new one as set by SetBuffer.`

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding you, but your log doesn't show any relevant information regarding the issue you're describing, and it's not clear why you think this is what you're seeing. In fact, I can't see how that would happen as the only reentrancy I can see here is after one operation is complete - buffer is fully utilized.